# can't have '<' inside a paragraph in react.js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have a `<p>` which has a text containing a '<' sign, and the code editor is giving me this error:

Unexpected token. Did you mean `{'>'}` or `&gt;`?

the code is like:

```
...
<p>
some text some text some text < and some text some text
</p>
...
```

how can I have this sign '<' in the text inside `<p>` ?

Comment: Replace < with `&lt;`? These are reserved characters in html and there's no direct way of writing these in html but to use entities.

Comment: @painotpi thank you so much, I didn't know that the '&lt;' is equivalent for '<'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use &lt; for '<' symbol and &gt; for '>'

Please look at https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_symbols.asp for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to display < as text inside html (or jsx that will turn into html), you can't just type special char. Instead, use '`&#60;`' for '<' and '`&#62;`' for '>'.
For more information check this: https://www.rapidtables.com/web/html/html-codes.html

Comment: putting the sign inside quotes didn't solve the problem, but the website is very useful, thank you so much

Comment: I'm sorry, the stackoverflow text editor changed the code to the character. Fixed it